# PHP if statement compare 3 dates

Tags: php, if-statement

I am having trouble writing if statement

there are the 3 variables

```
$date = 1985-11-01;

$date2 = 2005-11-08;

$date3 = 2006-11-08;
```

and here is my if statement.

```
if($date > $date2 && $date < $date3) {
            // dob is between the limits
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            // dob is outside the limits
            return FALSE;
        }
```

What I am try to do is, if $date is not in between $date2 and $date3, return false. I am very tired today and my brain is not working, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly isn't working, if your dates are already stored as UNIX timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strtotime` to ensure you compare correctly.

```
$date = strtotime('1985-11-01'); //499680000

$date2 = strtotime('2005-11-08'); //1131436800

$date3 = strtotime('2006-11-08'); //1162972800
```

When you do your logic, look at the Unix generated timestamps...

Comment: @Nanne It was burning me up inside.

Comment: The PHP DateTime object may be more intuitive and flexible (can handle pre-epoch dates) to use.

Comment: @sanchises it wasn't that popular back in 2012

Comment: @Kermit Oh deary me, forgot to check the DateTime of the question... :)

Comment: @sanchises no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

convert your variables to time objects using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

`$my_date = strtotime('08/11/2012');`

Comment: Yes my variables are like that already, I just thought I would save time and put the dates

Answer (score 0):

```
//using strtotime convert your date(s) in time stamp then your checking will be correctly worked.

$date = strtotime('1985-11-01');

$date2 = strtotime('2005-11-08');

$date3 = strtotime('2006-11-08');

if($date > $date2 && $date < $date3) 
        return true;
else
        return false;
```